# How does this lambda function work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a function with this signature:

```
public DeleteCommand(IService service, 
    Func<bool> canExecute, Action<ContactModel> deleted)
```

and code which calls it:

```
Delete = new DeleteCommand(
                Service, 
                ()=>CanDelete,
```

I don't understand what `()=>CanDelete` exactly means. Being a `Func<bool>` it must return some value.

```
()=>
```

means it has no input parameters. But what is the value returned? why there is no `return`
in the lambda? Something like `()=> return CanDelete`?

Answer (score 9):

An expression lambda, which is what you have shown, returns the result of the expression following the `=>`.  The `return` keyword is inferred, and in fact cannot be explicitly included.  A statement lambda (which is of the form `() => { someStatements;}`) does *not* infer a return value, and requires an explicit `return` if it is not `void`.

Comment: Or, in other words (hoping to help clarify), `() => CanDelete` means `() => { return CanDelete; }`.